# typescript: inference failing on generic type when using arrow function

Tags: typescript, types, rxjs, ngrx

I would expect that given the setup below, that the type of `data` would be inferred correctly as the inner type of the `of` observable, eg `number`.

There's some ngrx specific types in here but it seems like the problem is unrelated to them. The following snippet fails type check because `data` is seen as `unknown`

Edit: [reduced example with all types defined on playground =>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggYxASwPYDsDCAnKBDEVbAHgBUYBeGPdMAPkpgG9xoAuGUgX1ElkRQZSfYnAZU4MKAA8QUdABMAzvCRosuAkWLJ0AMyjZODAPycYHdFABuh3tBgB5AEZLD1vM4A2UMuOa6Vtgc3ADcwMAIGEogMKh6jH4AFNIhAJQcLm7YHt6+pOIMSUyBhhzSXGmR0bF4ahgcAuo4+IQkMdi6AOb+TDCsUBwA5HWC6DDoeAC2UEMwPMC6cth6dfz16ABKUEoQGAqGjhAgSmQANPBSsvLKqmMtWtgMTMAwcXrC7PDhb3gQyABlECaKYcJKjdSfQZ3SEiMRpSgMLLuTw+Pw-OLoAEAVwQCB2SjBCgIeHSiKcrhReWISjAU2cqC8dHCCz02PQG2oG22u32hnOlxkckUKiaGAebToSVQEEa3J2e0Uh2Op1IF3hHGsqGQCmYCyi6Bi70cVkYSQRFAY8SSAEYqsAIRgeYqDthiq93lCOI70GcPX9AcD8KCYEkIHgwF5UHgFBarXowxGozGAHQ+dBdEAACzSfoA9Hm3tR-kCQRx4iaoH63hgcXiCRxiSA8OS+k28CnCKXuubQjAALIELMp7CodkKJLttJ93AgbHYcbWgF0hlec1pLh+yqhIA)

```js
interface ActionResponderOpts<T, A extends ActionCreator> {
  ofType: A;
  apiStream: (actionType: ActionType<A>) => Observable<T>;
  onSuccess: (data: T) => Observable<Action>;
}

function actionResponder<T, A extends ActionCreator>(op: ActionResponderOpts<T, A>): void {}

actionResponder({
  ofType: SignIn,
  apiStream: payload => of(payload.email.length),
  onSuccess: data => { data.toString(); Math.round(data); return from([])},
});
```

---

A way to force a correct (but useless) type inference using a dummy function.

```js
const ofOne = () => of(1)

actionResponder({
  ofType: SignIn,
  apiStream: ofOne,
  onSuccess: data => { data.toString(); Math.round(data); return from([])},
});
```

---

It's not clear to me why the first should fail type check when this doesnt.

Comment:  I guess the generic type parameter in `of()` is being inferred too late for it to be useful in determining `T`.  You might have to annotate some of the types in the signature of `apiStream` such as `apiStream: (payload: string) => of(payload.length)` (in your reduced example).